# C++ pushing even numbers in an even stack and odd numbers in an odd stack

Tags: c++, stack

I'm trying to verify if the current element is even and push it into an even stack and if not to push it into an odd stack without using the  library. I want to push 6 into the even stack delete it from the first stack using pop and so on

```
| Odd stack| First Stack | | Even stack| 
| -------- |     4       | |     6     |
|    5     |     12      | |     12    |
|    3     |     3       | |     4     |
|          |     5       | |           |
|          |     6       | |           |
```

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct nod {
    int info;
    nod* next;
};

nod* l;
int n;

nod* push(int info, nod* l) {
    nod* aux;
    aux = new nod;
    aux->info = info;
    aux->next = l;
    return aux;
}

nod* pop(nod* l) {
    nod *aux1, *aux2;
    if (l != NULL) {
        aux1 = l;
        aux2 = l->next;
        cout << "\nVoi sterge nodul care contine:" << aux1->info << endl;
        delete aux1;
        return aux2;
    } else {
        cout << "\n Stiva este goala. Nu am ce sa sterg." << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}

// creating stack
void creare_stiva() {
    nod* a;
    int info;
    ifstream f("in.txt");
    f >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f >> info;
        l = push(info, l);
    }
}
// displaying stack
void afisare_stiva(nod* a) {
    a = l;
    if (a == NULL)
        cout << "Lista nu exista";
    else {
        cout << "\nElementele listei sunt: ";
        while (a) {
            cout << a->info << " | ";
            a = a->next;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    creare_stiva();
    afisare_stiva(l);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried testing if the element is odd or even but i don't know how to push it in an even stack and then delete it
How do I create 2 stacks, one even and one odd to then put the elements from the first stack and then delete them as I go?

```
void testing() {
    int info;
    while (l) {
        if (l -> info % 2 == 0) {

            l = push(info, l)
            l = l -> next;
        } else {
            l = l -> next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by formatting the code in a readable manor ... PS: you don't ask a question...

Comment: The first step to having more than one of anything is avoiding global variables.

Comment: `std::stack<int> even, odd; ... if ( num%2 ) odd.push(num); else even.push(num);` --

Answer (score 0):

First, create 2 stacks and name them like oddStack and evenStack. Then check if the number is odd or even. If the number is even, push it to evenStack; if the number is odd, push it to oddStack.

Comment: Please be more clear in the answer, add an example code, or something that can help the users to understand the concept

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).